# Какая разница между i++ и ++i?

Tags: javascript, c++

Какая разница между `i++` и `++i`?

Возьмем как пример строку:

```
for (i = ceil(a); i <= floor(b); i++)
cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: ++i сначала возвращает значение, потом увеличивает его, i++ сначала увеличивает, потом возвращает

Comment: В *данном контексте* - никакой.

Comment: @Harry, я рандом код узял, незнал что тут есть тастолько большие тонкощи.

Comment: @ThisMan Наверное, лучше - "возвращает значение переменной, которое в ней было до увеличения".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никакой.

```
for (i = ceil(a); i <= floor(b); i++)
```

Здесь нужно просто увеличить значение переменной на единицу.

---

А так (когда значение переменной *возвращаемое* оператором используется) - разница есть:

```js
var i = 1;
var j = 1;
console.log(i++, ++j);
console.log(i, j);
```

Причем именно такая, какая описана в определении этих операторов.

---

C++ код для данного примера:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 1, j = 1;
  cout << i++ << ", " << ++j << endl;
  cout << i   << ", " << j   << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

В связи с наступлением на нас шаблонов в С++, рекомендуется писать в циклах ++i а не i++. Это связано с тем, что прединкремент для классов обычно реализуется проще, чем постинкремент (как минимум, не надо хранить старое значение для возврата). Поэтому, если к примеру в шаблон в качестве типа счетчика цикла будет подставлено не просто целое, а сверхдлинное целое, то внутри циклов будет меньше ненужной работы.

Comment: Чё  ж так сложновато.... Терминология.. даже поовини слов мне не извесна. Ушёл в гугл...

Comment: @Witalik Если сейчас не понятно, то не парьтесь. Если будете работать с С++ и шаблонами, то поймете по ходу работы.

Comment: Мой уровень знаний не настолько велик чтобы знать что такое "постинкремент" если я задаю такой на первой згляд простой вопрос, но если углубитса...

Comment: @Witalik "++i" это прединкремент, а "i++" это постинкремент.

Comment: Молча поставлю плюсик на ответ.. и пойму что у меня дымок пошел...

Answer (score 5):

`i++` возвращает `i`, потом увеличивает на 1.
`++i` увеличивает `i` на 1, потом возвращает.

Answer (score 5):

`i++` сначала берёт значение переменной, а потом увеличивает переменную `i` на `1`, а `++i` наоборот, сначала увеличивает значение переменной `i` на `1`, а потом берёт значение `i`.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к другим ответам добавлю, что операции постинкремента и прединкремента имеют разные приоритеты. Постинкремент имеет выше приоритет чем преинкремент, поэтому код

```
int val = 1;
++val++;      // Ошибка компиляции!
```

приведет к ошибке компиляции. Также код вроде

```
int val = 1;
val++++++;    // Ошибка компиляции!
```

вызовет ошибку компиляции. Но код

```
int val = 1;
++++++val;    // Все хорошо!
```

скомпилируется и выполнится без ошибок.
Все вышесказанное также применимо к операциям декремента.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в возвращаемом значении и квалификаторе типа *(свойстве)*.
В пре-инкременте `++ i` увеличивается переменная `i` и возвращается уже увеличенная **l-value** *(живая)* ссылка на эту-же переменную.
А в пост-инкременте `i ++` возвращаемое значение имеет тип **r-value** *(очень временное значение, которое равно **бывшему** значению переменной)* и дальнейшее увеличение переменной происходит потом.

```
int i = 7 ;
int x = ( ++ i ) ;
// i == 8 ; x == 8

int i = 7 ;
int x = ( i ++ ) ;
// i == 8 ; x == 7
```

Разница у **l-value** ссылки и **r-value** значения в том, что у живой ссылки есть возможность взять её адрес и проводить дальнейшие инкременты. А у временного значения их нет.

```
int * l = & ( ++ i ) ; // можно
int * r = & ( i ++ ) ; // нельзя

++ ( ++ i ) ; // можно
(i ++ ) ++ ; // нельзя
```

Продлить жизнь у временного значения можно, если сначала прикрепить его к **r-value** ссылке.

```
int &  lval = ++ i ;
// lval == i
// & lval == & i

int && rval = i ++ ;
// rval != i
// & rval != & i
```