# Чем отличается префиксный инкремент ++i от постфиксного i++ в цикле for. C++

Tags: c++

В чем разница между постфиксным и префиксным инкрементом в данном коде

```
for(int  i=0;i<size;++i)
{
cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
} 

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: тут ничем. Компилятор умный, сам всё сделает. Чисто формально, `++i` не создаёт временной переменной

Comment: В цикле ни чем. Префиксный сначала инкрементирует, потом отдаёт значение, постфиксный сначала отдаёт значение, потом инкрементирует. В общем, слева направо читай :)

Comment: Имеено в даном случае ничем в плане "результат выполнения" но небольшая разница в алгоритме о которой уже сказали выше, хотя и в цикле можно подобрать такое выражение что будет играть роль.

Comment: @AlexF Если компилятор достаточно умный и оптимизация включена, то разницы в скорости может и не быть.

Comment: @AlexF *Для класса (например, итератор) ++i выполняется быстрее.* Это смотря что и как написать :)

Comment: Если даже компилятор сам будет оптимизировать, то всеравно лучше использовать преинкремент там, где  постинкремент   не лучше выражает логику кода. Зачем  добавлять работу компилятору, если  можно самому написать ++а  вместо а++?

Comment: думаю, что надо сделать платной возможность комментировать подобные вопросы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какая разница между i++ и ++i?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055621/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-i-%d0%b8-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно обсуждали такой вопрос.

[Какая разница между i++ и ++i?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055621/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-i-%D0%B8-i/1055629#1055629)

Повторю свой ответ на тот вопрос:

> В связи с наступлением на нас шаблонов в С++, рекомендуется писать в
>   циклах ++i а не i++. Это связано с тем, что прединкремент для классов
>   обычно реализуется проще, чем постинкремент (как минимум, не надо
>   хранить старое значение для возврата). Поэтому, если к примеру в
>   шаблон в качестве типа счетчика цикла будет подставлено не просто
>   целое, а сверхдлинное целое, то внутри циклов будет меньше ненужной
>   работы.

Comment: Нужно не ответ дублировать, а закрывать вопрос как дубликат. Плюс, в будущем постарайтесь в ответе лишь по теме писать без оценочных суждений о других участниках.

Comment: А это не дубликат ответа, это просто еще один взгляд на проблему. Наряду с эквивалентностью постинкремента и прединкремента для целого типа, например.

Comment: Я про вопрос. Явный ж дубликат.

Comment: Извините, но я не могу на себя взять такое тяжелое решение, что считать дубликатом вопроса, а что не считать.